# Почему в аргумент функции не передается элемент?

Tags: javascript, функции

Помогите решить проблему. На странице расположены карточки с фото и подписью к фото. Карточки генерируются из массива с помощью template. Реализован попап который всплывает при клике на картинку, и состоит из фото и подписи, линк на фото и текст подписи берутся из карточки на фото которой кликнули. Всплытие и наполнение попапа осуществляет функция fillPopup из кода ниже, но проблема в том что в ее аргумент приходит #document-fragment вместо нужного элемента. Не могу понять почему.

```
const cardTemplate = document.querySelector('.template-card').content;
const cardsList = document.querySelector('.cards__items');
const imageOfPopup = document.querySelector('.popup__img');
const titleOfPopupImage = document.querySelector('.image-title');
const newCard = {name: "", link: ""};

  //создает карту
  function createCard(el) {
    const card = cardTemplate.cloneNode(true);
    card.querySelector('.cards__title').textContent = el.name;
    card.querySelector('.cards__image').src = el.link;
    setListeners(card);
  cardsList.prepend(card);
  }

  //вешает слушатели
  function setListeners(ele) {
    debugger;
    ele.querySelector('.cards__delet-button').addEventListener('click', handleDelete);
    ele.querySelector('.cards__image').addEventListener('click', () => {fillPopup(ele)});
    ele.querySelector('.cards__like-button').addEventListener('click', like);
  }

//наполняет popup с картинкой
function fillPopup(item) {
  imageOfPopup.src = item.querySelector('.cards__image').src;
  titleOfPopupImage.textContent = item.querySelector('.cards__title').textContent;
  openPopup(popupImg);
  };
```

Comment: Что конкретно означает "ничего"? Что пишет console.log при попытке отпечатать этот аргумент?

Comment: Не может быть. `function setListeners(ele) { console.log("setListeners", ele);...`, `function fillPopup(item) { console.log("fillPopup", item);...`

Comment: Не может быть. Вы уже добавили вызовы `console.log`, как показано в комментарии выше? Что в консоли браузера?

Comment: Похоже, моё врождённое недоверие к дебаггерам небезосновательно)

Comment: в консоле браузера #document-fragment

Comment: Вы поэтому не хотите делать что Вам говорят?

Comment: В каком случае? Tам еще должно быть "setListeners" или "fillPopup".

Comment: в случае с setListeners

Comment: Но Вы же говорите, что аргумент равен `null` в `fillPopup`.

Comment: То есть аргумент уже не `null`?

Comment: Нет, сейчас еще раз дебажил и в аргументе fillPopup #document-fragment, сорри что в заблуждение ввел

Comment: создайте работающий пример - кнопка "Фрагмент кода" в редакторе вопроса

Comment: Проблему решил. Если у кого будет похожая проблема то имейте ввиду что в функцию с наполнением попапа с картинкой надо было передавать не dom элемент с карточкой а объект из массива с линком и заголовком

Answer (score 1):

Вы вызываете `fillPopup` где-то еще, передавая в нее результат какого-нибудь `querySelector`, который возвращает `null`.

Comment: fillPopup вызывается только при клике на .cards__image

Answer (score 0):

в функцию с наполнением попапа с картинкой надо было передавать не dom элемент с карточкой а объект из массива с линком и заголовком